# Cannot see email from other Folders in a Shared Mailbox with PS script

Tags: powershell, outlook, office365, exchange-server, office-automation

I have a script to check mails that are in my inbox in Outlook. I also can check mails from another mailbox by this script:

```
Function Get-OutlookItems {
    Param (
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
        [String]$SharedMailbox,
        [Switch]$IncludeSubfolders
    )

    Add-Type -Assembly "Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook" | Out-Null
    $olFolders = "Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.olDefaultFolders" -as [type]
    $outlook = New-Object -ComObject Outlook.Application
    $namespace = $outlook.GetNamespace("MAPI")

    # Resolve the shared mailbox folder based on the email address
    $sharedMailboxAddressEntry = $namespace.CreateRecipient($SharedMailbox)
    $sharedMailboxAddressEntry.Resolve()

    if ($sharedMailboxAddressEntry.Resolved) {
        $sharedMailboxFolder = $namespace.GetSharedDefaultFolder($sharedMailboxAddressEntry, $olFolders::olFolderInbox)
    } else {
        throw "Unable to resolve the shared mailbox."
    }

    if ($IncludeSubfolders) {
        $folderItems = $sharedMailboxFolder.Items.Restrict
    } else {
        $folderItems = $sharedMailboxFolder.Items
    }

    $folderItems | Select-Object -Property Subject, ReceivedTime, Importance, SenderName
}


Get-OutlookItems -SharedMailbox 'shared@domain.com' -IncludeSubFolders
```

but it seems that its only displaying my Inbox. How can I display all folders from this shared mailbox? Or is this not possible?

Comment: Wasn't able to test here but once the mbx mounted, you must crete an handle to it

Something like
  $OutlookFolder = $NameSpace.folders('shared@domain.com') ; 
  $OutlookFolder = $OutlookFolder.folders('Inbox')

Answer (score 0):

Calling the `Restict` method to get items from subfolders doesn't make any sense:

```
$folderItems = $sharedMailboxFolder.Items.Restrict
```

The `Restrict` method (as well as `Find`/`FindNext` methods) of the `Items` class allows getting items that correspond to the specified search criteria. That is for entirely different tasks.

To get subfolders you need to use the [Folders](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.folder.folders) property which returns the `Folders` collection that represents all the folders contained in the specified Folder. The following sample code (C#) first obtains the root folder for the default store by using the `GetRootFolder()` method. It then calls the `EnumerateFolders` method on the root folder. `EnumerateFolders` takes in a root folder and walks through the folders of the default store that the root folder represents. `EnumerateFolders` first uses the `Folders` property to obtain the subfolders of the root Folder object. `EnumerateFolders` is then called recursively to enumerate all the folders in a hierarchy.

```
private void EnumerateFoldersInDefaultStore()
{
    Outlook.Folder root =
        Application.Session.
        DefaultStore.GetRootFolder() as Outlook.Folder;
    EnumerateFolders(root);
}

// Uses recursion to enumerate Outlook subfolders.
private void EnumerateFolders(Outlook.Folder folder)
{
    Outlook.Folders childFolders =
        folder.Folders;
    if (childFolders.Count > 0)
    {
        foreach (Outlook.Folder childFolder in childFolders)
        {
            // Write the folder path.
            Debug.WriteLine(childFolder.FolderPath);
            // Call EnumerateFolders using childFolder.
            EnumerateFolders(childFolder);
        }
    }
}
```

Iterating recursively over all subfolders you may get all items/folders.

Comment: I’m not familiar with c# how can I do this in PS?

Comment: The Outlook object model is common for all kind of programming languages. In the sample code you can find the sequence of property and method calls to iterate over all subfolders recursively.

Comment: Thanks but still I need to execute this in powershell any guidance how to?

Comment: SO is not for requesting ready-made solutions. Try to implement things described, if something doesn't work you can always ask here (another post with separate questions).